# CSS 3 - Scale transition snaps back in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, transition

I have an issue , I have the following code I am using for increasing the scale using CSS3 transition , at the end it snaps back to its original scale after increasing.

CSS:

```
.big{


        transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        display:inline;
}
.big:hover{

-webkit-transform:scale(1.4);
}
```

HTML :

```
<h1 class = "big">Typo</h1>
```

Comment: This is not related to the solution, but your logo is not nice at all...

Comment: Haha! Nice that you understand arabic :3

Comment: As I see it, be nice to others and they will be nice to you :)  Sorry I do not know the answer to your question though

Comment: you mean you want to stay at scale 1.4 after mouseLeave !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using inline-block instead of inline (also, it's recommended to add compatibility to the rest of the browsers as well).

CSS:

```
.big {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
}
.big:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="big">Typo</h1>
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XbUC8/